# Unable to join data by field value

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, qgis-processing, attribute-joins, latitude-longitude

i have a dataset which contain object_id, poi_x and poi_y and another data set with same object_ids but different poi_x and poi_y. i want to join poi_x and poi_y from second dataset to first dataset. but failed to join. please any one tell me why it happens.[image]

Comment: Probably the coordinates are a bit different. Create a buffer for one data-set with a reasonable radius (e.g. 1-2 m) then use spatial join (join attributes by location) for the buffer and the other point layer using "contains" geometric predicate.

Comment: attribute field is created but data in that field is not joining. im joining data based on objectid in both files

Comment: Are they the same data type

Comment: @BERA Yes they are

Comment: can you show us an example feature from each table

Comment: Are they in the same CRS?